# numpy multicore error while using matplotlib

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, matplotlib

while i try to run a matplotlib example program it shows "Failed to import numpy multicore array".Then i upgrade the numpy version from 1.12 to 1.15 on both the python versions 2.7 and 3.5(in raspberry pi python 2.7 is a default version).
The code am using is:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.plot([1, 2, 3, 4])
plt.ylabel('some numbers')
plt.show()
```

while running this code it show some different error that

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/numpy/core/__init__.py", line 16, in <module>
    from . import multiarray
ImportError: libf77blas.so.3: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pi/hdg.py", line 1, in <module>
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/matplotlib/__init__.py", line 141, in <module>
    from . import cbook, rcsetup
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/matplotlib/cbook/__init__.py", line 33, in <module>
    import numpy as np
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/numpy/__init__.py", line 142, in <module>
    from . import add_newdocs
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/numpy/add_newdocs.py", line 13, in <module>
    from numpy.lib import add_newdoc
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/numpy/lib/__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
    from .type_check import *
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/numpy/lib/type_check.py", line 11, in <module>
    import numpy.core.numeric as _nx
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/numpy/core/__init__.py", line 26, in <module>
    raise ImportError(msg)
ImportError: 
Importing the multiarray numpy extension module failed.  Most
likely you are trying to import a failed build of numpy.
If you're working with a numpy git repo, try `git clean -xdf` (removes all
files not under version control).  Otherwise reinstall numpy.
```

Original error was: `libf77blas.so.3: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`

how to overcome this one?

Comment: works fine for me, python 3.6

Comment: How about your numpy version

Comment: I laways update them, they are the latest version. I think you might just install minconda and then install matplotlib. I am using miniconda. numpy '1.15.4', matplotlib '3.0.1'

Comment: Why should I install miniconda??

Comment: it simplifies installing third party packages and manages dependecies specially if you are a windows user.

Comment: No, am using Linux

Comment: probably there is a problem with your installation.